# Starling not displaying graphic

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

Hi guys i am new to AS3 and to Starling i am having problem displaying an image in a different class. it does show on my game menu class but i wanted it to show on my play game class.

so i got 3 classes Main that starts the starling that runs GameMenu class.

"GameMenu class"
package {

```
import starling.display.BlendMode;
import starling.display.Button;
import starling.display.Image;
import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.events.Event;

public class GameMenu extends Sprite {

    private var bg:Image;
    private var gameLogo:Image;
    private var playBtn:Button;
    private var rankBtn:Button;
    private var settingBtn:Button;

    private var inGame:PlayGame;


    public function GameMenu ()
    {
        super ();

        this.addEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage (event:Event):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        drawScreen ();
    }

    private function drawScreen ():void
    {
        bg = new Image(Assets.getAtlas().getTexture(("Background.png")));
        bg.blendMode = BlendMode.NONE;
        this.addChild(bg);

        gameLogo = new Image(Assets.getAtlas().getTexture(("GameLogo.png")));
        gameLogo.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - gameLogo.width/2;
        gameLogo.y = 30;
        this.addChild(gameLogo);

        playBtn = new Button(Assets.getAtlas().getTexture("PlayBtn.png"));
        playBtn.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - playBtn.width/2;
        playBtn.y = 450;
        playBtn.addEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onPlayClick);
        this.addChild(playBtn);

        rankBtn = new Button(Assets.getAtlas().getTexture("RankBtn.png"));
        rankBtn.x = rankBtn.bounds.left + 60;
        rankBtn.y = 600;
        rankBtn.addEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onRankClick);
        this.addChild(rankBtn);

        settingBtn = new Button(Assets.getAtlas().getTexture("SettingBtn.png"));
        settingBtn.x = settingBtn.bounds.right + 60;
        settingBtn.y = 600;
        settingBtn.addEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onSettingClick);
        this.addChild(settingBtn);

    }

    private function onRankClick (event:Event):void
    {
        trace("LEADERBOARD BUTTON HIT")
    }

    private function onSettingClick (event:Event):void
    {
        trace("SETTING SCREEN BUTTON HIT")
    }

    private function onPlayClick (event:Event):void
    {
        playBtn.removeEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onPlayClick);
        trace("PLAY BUTTON HIT")

        gameLogo.visible = false;
        playBtn.visible = false;
        rankBtn.visible = false;
        settingBtn.visible = false;
        //bg.visible = false;
        inGame = new PlayGame();
    }


}
```

}

this class works perfectly now.

"PlayGame class"

package {

```
import starling.display.Image;
import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.events.Event;

public class PlayGame extends Sprite
{
    private var bubble:Image;

    public function PlayGame ()
    {
        trace("PlayGame");
        super ();

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage2);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage2 (event:Event):void
    {
        trace("OnAddedToStage");
        this.removeEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage2);

        drawScreen ();
    }

    public function drawScreen ():void
    {
         trace("Bubble");
         bubble = new Image(Assets.getAtlas().getTexture(("Bubble.png")));
         bubble.x = 100;
         bubble.y = 100;
         this.addChild(bubble);
    }


}
```

}

the bubble image is now showing and i don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

They are too much parenthesis, but this is not your issue

```
bubble = new Image(Assets.getAtlas().getTexture(("Bubble.png")));
//is less clean/readable than
bubble = new Image(Assets.getAtlas().getTexture("Bubble.png"));
```

When facing this kind of issues, if starling/air doesn't report any errors, you should try to be sure the display object are currently rendered.

Try to apply a color instead of the texture.

```
bubble = new Image( Texture.fromColor(64,64,0xff99ff) );
```

If this code shows a fancy rectangle of 64 pixel/side, you trouble come from your texture atlas or texture. Be sure to have a valided atlas, validates frames, and names.

If this code doesn't show the facy rectangle, your issue doesn't come from the texture atlas or texture, but more possibly from the display list of starling.

And in your case,
I think you should just need to addChild the Ingame in your GameMenu class :

GameMenu :

```
private function onPlayClick (event:Event):void
{
    //... your stuff
    inGame = new PlayGame();

    this.parent.addChild(inGame);
}
```

And it should works.